Can I Use the Same Process for Adding Icons and Themes to Ubuntu Unity 24.04 as for Ubuntu Gnome?
All the search answers I've found so far for adding themes and icons to the Unity desktop (I'm running Ubuntu Unity 24.04, with Unity 7.7) are dated back to the original Unity. The links shown are broken, and I can't get the Nooblab link to work, although the web site is up and running. Where can I find additional themes and icons to add to Unity Tweak, and how do I add them to the current version? Thanks in advance.

Short answer: Yes, you can.
Unity also is a desktop based on GTK, so any tricks to theme will also work on the Unity desktop.
